Custom Response headers are not receiving in to client side
I have two servers, httpd server has launching in UI application and another server has in Spring boot application.
In spring boot rest end point sending the custom response headers to UI, but that is not coming into the UI, but if I call the rest end point through postman then I can see the custom response headers.
My doubt here is do I need to add any configuration in the httpd.conf file or not
port : 8080
 final HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity<byte[]> httpEntity = null;
        if(true){
            header.set("warning", "Some warning message");
            httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(new ConnectorFileVO().getData(), header);
            return httpEntity;
        } 

port : 80 UI
 Angular JS UI Code
 ProductConfigService.downloadProduct(req).then(function (response) {
               var warning = null
               if(response.headers) {
                   warning = response.headers['warning'];
               } else {
                   console.log('Some error');
               }
               var filename = null;
              if(response.headers['content-disposition']) {
                   filename = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1];
                   downloadActualFile(response.data, filename);
                
               }
            deferred.resolve();

        }, function (fault) {
            deferred.reject(fault);
            toastr.error(fault.faultDescription, $filter('i18n')('error'));
        });

        return deferred.promise;

Response from direct spring boot server
http://localhost:8080/spring-boot/configure/download

Response from UI server
http://localhost/spring-boot/api/configure/download

apache Httpd.conf
SSLProxyEngine on ProxyPass /spring-boot/api/ http://localhost:8080/spring-boot/ ProxyPassReverse /spring-boot/api/ http://localhost:8080/spring-boot/

@NarenMurali Please verify, more code added. If anything missing please let me know

Did you try with X-Warning instead of warning?

What are the request headers in Postman? Can you share the screenshot?

Request headers contains aauth token and body contains some data

@Olivier Thanks for the answer its worked, do u have any idea why its not worked, both are strings only right?
